# Web2py working with DB2

Tags: python, db2, web2py, pyodbc, unixodbc

somebody know how to run Web2py over Linux using a remote DB2 server?

I tried using pyodbc, but is very poor the documentation over it

I can't find a step to step guide for it.

my config files:

odbcinst.ini:

```
[DB2]
Description     = DB2 Driver
Driver          = /opt/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so
FileUsage       = 1
DontDLClose     = 1
```

odbc.ini

```
[test]
Description     = Test to DB2
Driver          = DB2
```

trying to Connect:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={DB2};SERVER=172.16.1.35;DATABASE=log10;UID=db2admin;PWD=passs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "127.0.0.1".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "111", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\n (-30081) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance
Christian

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the DAL? http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06

Comment: Im using Web2py DAL, but it doesnt have a direct Db connection, instead you need f/e pyodbc for this

Comment: So using the connection string "db2://username:password@test" doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical communication problem error.
Before to connect, try to check the connectivity:

What is the instance port? default is 50000, but you did not specify one in the connect statement.

What is the ip address / hostname? if your case it seems it is 172.16.1.35

Try a telnet in that port

```
telnet 172.16.1.35 50000
```

If you can establish a connection, you will get a message like this:

```
Trying 172.16.1.35...
Connected to hostname.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you have connection problems, you will see

```
Trying 172.16.1.35...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

As far as I see, you have to check the instance port, and the connection settings prior to execute your program.
There could be a firewall problem, have you checked the opened ports?
Try a netstat -nato in the server, to see if the DB2 instance is active and listening the port (currently unknown)

Comment: The network communication is done, I can connect through telnet only, using pyodbc I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I use PHP to connect to a remote DB2 server and this is what my /etc/odbc.ini file looks like:

```
[primary]
Description             = primary
Driver                  = iseries
System                  = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
UserID                  = xxxxxxxxxx
Password                = xxxxxxxxxx
Naming                  = 0
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
Database                = XXXXXXXXXX
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
```

And my /etc/odbcinst.ini files looks like this:

```
[iseries]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

I mention this because I think you're missing some information in your configuration files.